# Нужен совет java/php

Tags: php, java, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, хотел бы получить совет.
В общем, знаю java/spring/html/css ну и js немного
, могу написать небольшие веб-сервисы, но так таковой работы в городе нет, а если и есть, то только на полный день, поэтому даже смысла не вижу пробовать, а при учёбе в вузе и на военной кафедре на полный день как-бы не будет оставаться времени. Да и честно говоря, думаю что с java может не получится, ибо там нужны сразу серьёзные спецы, а на джунов как я понимаю очень большая конкуренция.
В связи с этим подумал об php. Вакансии даже в моём городе есть в более менее нормальном кол-ве (джуниор/стажировки), чего не сказать про java. Почти везде берут студентов. Так же есть возможность работать удалённо. Но это всё мои выводы судя по hh, я могу ошибаться, и всё не так радужно. 
Просто время идёт, подрабатывать уже хочется, а с java я далеко не могу уйти пока. Хотел бы спросить, стоит ли сейчас уходить в php ? Если да, то как именно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На ваш вопрос нельзя дать однозначного ответа. Спросом пользуется любой более-менее известный язык, но в части уровня навыков вы правы - очень много программистов имеют уровень junior и очень мало pro. Советую повышать уровень в любом из языков на ваш выбор. Спросом в ближайшие годы будет пользоваться как Java, так и PHP. Просто в PHP более низкий порог входа, чем в Java. И здесь конкуренция не меньше, а даже больше.

Что касается самой работы - попробуйте брать заказы на наших или зарубежных биржах, там можно найти как что-то длительное, так и небольшие проекты на пару дней.